# Issue with render() method in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm currently trying to fetch data from an endpoint, but I keep getting a error stating that my render method have an unexpected token. Any help is appreciated.

Also I'm not sure If I am bracketing into the data correctly either.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


class GetAMovieTitle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {movies: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData()
  }

fetchData() {
    fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json', {method: "GET"})
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) =>{

     this.setState({ movies: response.movies})
         console.log(this.state.movies)
         console.log(response.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
  })
  
 render(){
    return (
      <div>
          <h1> Currently Showing:</h1>
          <p>{this.state.movies[0]}</p>
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <GetAMovieTitle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Typo? Seems to be missing 2 closing braces, for `fetchData()` and the `class`. – Note: SyntaxErrors can only direct you to where the parser realized something's not right. The cause for it can often be before that.

Comment: You may also wish to initialize movies to an empty array, so that the render method does not throw a TypeError. Also, it looks like the json provided by the endpoint has a 'movies' property (in your response callback, you are trying to access the 'data' property which does not exist on the returned object).

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(` should be outside the class, so add closing bracket  as mentioned in above comments and you are done :)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski  Good Catch, I updated the fetchData() function and missing Class curly brace. Now my fetch function doesn't work. It returns Failed to fetch

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, I have corrected two of the Syntax errors(closing brackets missing for `fetchData` and `class`) and some eslint warnings.

```
export default LoginStack;

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


class GetAMovieTtile extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { movies: null };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData() {
        fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json', { method: "GET" })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ movies: response.data });
            console.log(this.state.movies);
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <h1> Currently Showing:</h1>
            <p>{this.state.movies[0]}</p>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <GetAMovieTtile />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: still a few errors, I updated it and correct a few typos. Now I have error with the fetch function

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two brackets in your code. I've also added a null check in your render method - you may want to replace this with a loading indicator or similiar. This will avoid printing console errors if your component gets mounted before it contains any state.

See below:

```js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


class GetAMovieTitle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { movies: null };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData()
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json', { method: "GET" })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {

        this.setState({ movies: response.data })
        console.log(this.state.movies)
        console.log(response.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })
  }

    render(){
      if (!this.state.movies) {
        return null;
      }
      
      return (
        <div>
          <h1> Currently Showing:</h1>
          <p>{this.state.movies[0]}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

    ReactDOM.render(
      <GetAMovieTitle />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Comment: I updated the fetchData() function and missing Class curly brace. Now my fetch function doesn't work. It returns Failed to fetch